# How to remove normalization function on data?

Tags: r, normalization

I currently have my data scaled between the range of 0 and 1 using the following normalization function in R:

```
normalise <- function(x) {
  return((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}
```

The problem is I need to remove this function to rescale my data to the original metric units used.

Answer (score 3):

```
inv.normalize <- function(norm, x.min, x.max){
norm*(x.max-x.min)+x.min
}
```

Comment: How is the inv.normalize applied? using lappy?  rmnorm <- as.data.frame(lapply(sales_norm,inv.normalize))

Comment: @SonOfTenny `lapply` is appropriate if your data object is a list...